Rotating bitmap and keeping track of location on new image C#
If I rotate a bitmap and want to keep track of a point on the original image as translated on the new image, how would I achieve this. I essentially want to know where the top right corner of the original image is on the new rotated and expanded image, so I can draw to a graphics surface in the correct location. I'm using the following code to rotate the bitmap (originally taken from another post).
      public static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap origBmp, float angle)
      {
         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
         matrix.Translate(origBmp.Width / -2, origBmp.Height / -2, MatrixOrder.Append);
         matrix.RotateAt(angle, new Point(0, 0), MatrixOrder.Append);

         using (GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath())
         {
            // Transform image points by rotation matrix
            graphicsPath.AddPolygon(new Point[]
            {
               new Point(0, 0),
               new Point(origBmp.Width, 0),
               new Point(0, origBmp.Height)
            });

            graphicsPath.Transform(matrix);
            PointF[] pts = graphicsPath.PathPoints;

            Rectangle boundingBox = BoundingBox(origBmp, matrix);
            Bitmap bmpDest = new Bitmap(boundingBox.Width, boundingBox.Height);

            using (Graphics graphicsDest = Graphics.FromImage(bmpDest))
            {
               Matrix matrixDest = new Matrix();
               matrixDest.Translate(bmpDest.Width / 2, bmpDest.Height / 2, MatrixOrder.Append);
               graphicsDest.Transform = matrixDest;
               graphicsDest.DrawImage(origBmp, pts);
            }

            return bmpDest;
         }
      }

      private static Rectangle BoundingBox(
         Image img,
         Matrix matrix)
      {
         GraphicsUnit gu = new GraphicsUnit();
         Rectangle imgRect = Rectangle.Round(img.GetBounds(ref gu));

         // Transform the four points of the image, to get the resized bounding box.
         Point topLeft = new Point(imgRect.Left, imgRect.Top);
         Point topRight = new Point(imgRect.Right, imgRect.Top);
         Point bottomRight = new Point(imgRect.Right, imgRect.Bottom);
         Point bottomLeft = new Point(imgRect.Left, imgRect.Bottom);

         Point[] points = new Point[]
         {
            topLeft,
            topRight,
            bottomRight,
            bottomLeft
         };

         GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath(
            points,
            new byte[]
            {
               (byte)PathPointType.Start,
               (byte)PathPointType.Line,
               (byte)PathPointType.Line,
               (byte)PathPointType.Line
            });

         graphicsPath.Transform(matrix);
         return Rectangle.Round(graphicsPath.GetBounds());
      }

 
Specifically I'm trying to draw wind 'barbs' at the correct location and rotation.
I've attempted to use the same translation approach to translate the point on the original image, but with no luck.

Related and this one.

Not really, I'm using images of a more complex shape, rather than just a  rectangle.

Assuming the top-right corner of initial image is an anchor, what exactly should happens after rotation? Are you trying to translate rotated image so that it looks like it was rotated using top-right corner as origin point? Why not perform rotation around that point initially?

I'm just looking to keep track of the anchor point, as the origin the image gets drawn. The image needs to be resized to avoid any clipping.
